# Configuring multiple ProxyPassReverseCookiePath in Apache HTTP

Tags: apache-2.4, proxypass, cookies

I have a server with an Apache reverse proxy in front. The server machine contains 2 web applications running under:

- *localhost:8000/app* and exposed as *my.url.com/app1*
- *localhost:8001/app* and exposed as *my.url.com/app2*

They are essentially different versions of the webapp and we want them both up. **Both** webapps create a cookie like so:

`Set-Cookie: sessionid=as7d86fa98sg67; Path=/app; HttpOnly`

Note that there is no `Domain` property on the cookie header.

I have added 2 different `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` directives like so:

- ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /app /app1
- ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /app /app2

The goal is that each webapp will have its `Path=/app` transformed to the appropriate context. However the ProxyPassReverseCookiePath directives seem to override one another and don't have awareness of the webapp they run for.

TL;DR:

```
ProxyPass /app1/ http://localhost:8000/app/
ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://localhost:8000/app/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /app /app1

ProxyPass /app2/ http://localhost:8001/app/
ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://localhost:8001/app/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /app /app2
```

This configurations works, except for the cookie path property. For both cases it gets replaced with `Path=/app1/` whereas I'd like it to be specific to each app that handles the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching around the solution is to group the directives under a `<Location>` tag:

```
<Location /app1>
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /app /app1
</Location>

<Location /app2>
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /app /app2
</Location>
```

This way Apache knows to properly apply each directive depending on the origin of the response.

Comment: It seems the other parts `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` can go inside the `Location`.
In your test you put just the `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't remember (it's been a few years) but I guess it's not mandatory. Whatever works for you.